# In django, how can I unit test all links recursively every view (check for 200 OK), starting from a list of known URLs on my site

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, pytest

In a django application, how can I test if there are no broken links without explicitly writing a unit test for every single view?

The test should 'surf' to all links it finds on the site and test for a "200 OK" response.

Comment: Are you intending to check _external_ URLs too? That doesn't sound l like a good idea; an off-site resource going down shouldn't cause your tests to fail…

Comment: No, external URLs are excluded in the 'to_avoid_list'. This indeed keeps unit tests working independent of external behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following piece of code proved to be very useful to me.
It revealed some broken links immediately, so I want to share it here.

It traverses all links recursively, starting from a list of URLs, and checks for a 200 OK response.

A list of URLs to avoid can also be given.

Notes:

- Tested with django 1.8.16 & python 2.7
- Requires beatifulsoup4 (pip install beautifulsoup4)

Here we go:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.test import TestCase
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

VERBOSE = True


class TraverseLinksTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # By default, login as superuser
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_superuser('superuser1', 'superuser1@example.com', 'pwd')
        if self.client.login(username="superuser1@example.com", password="pwd"):
            if VERBOSE: print('\nLogin as superuser OK')
        else:
            raise BaseException('Login failed')

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Initialise your database here as needed
        pass

    def test_traverse_urls(self):
        # Fill these lists as needed with your site specific URLs to check and to avoid
        to_traverse_list = ['/mysite', '/mysite/sub-page']
        to_avoid_list = ['^/$', '^$', 'javascript:history\.back()', 'javascript:history\.go\(-1\)', '^mailto:.*', '.*github\.io.*']

        done_list = []
        error_list = []
        source_of_link = dict()
        for link in to_traverse_list:
            source_of_link[link] = 'initial'

        (to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, error_list, source_of_link) = \
            self.recurse_into_path(to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, error_list, source_of_link)

        print('END REACHED\nStats:')
        if VERBOSE: print('\nto_traverse_list = ' + str(to_traverse_list))
        if VERBOSE: print('\nto_avoid_list = ' + str(to_avoid_list))
        if VERBOSE: print('\nsource_of_link = ' + str(source_of_link))
        if VERBOSE: print('\ndone_list = ' + str(done_list))
        print('Followed ' + str(len(done_list)) + ' links successfully')
        print('Avoided ' + str(len(to_avoid_list)) + ' links')

        if error_list:
            print('!! ' + str(len(error_list)) + ' error(s) : ')
            for error in error_list:
                print(str(error) + ' found in page ' + source_of_link[error[0]])

            print('Errors found traversing links')
            assert False
        else:
            print('No errors')

    def recurse_into_path(self, to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, error_list, source_of_link):
        """ Dives into first item of to_traverse_list
            Returns: (to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, source_of_link)
        """

        if to_traverse_list:
            url = to_traverse_list.pop()

            if not match_any(url, to_avoid_list):
                print('Surfing to ' + str(url) + ', discovered in ' + str(source_of_link[url]))
                response = self.client.get(url, follow=True)

                if response.status_code == 200:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

                    text = soup.get_text()

                    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
                        new_link = link.get('href')
                        if VERBOSE: print('  Found link: ' + str(new_link))
                        if match_any(new_link, to_avoid_list):
                            if VERBOSE: print('    Avoiding it')
                        elif new_link in done_list:
                            if VERBOSE: print('    Already done, ignoring')
                        elif new_link in to_traverse_list:
                            if VERBOSE: print('    Already in to traverse list, ignoring')
                        else:
                            if VERBOSE: print('    New, unknown link: Storing it to traverse later')
                            source_of_link[new_link] = url
                            to_traverse_list.append(new_link)

                    done_list.append(url)
                    if VERBOSE: print('Done')
                else:
                    error_list.append((url, response.status_code))
                    to_avoid_list.append(url)

            if VERBOSE: print('Diving into next level')
            return self.recurse_into_path(to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, error_list, source_of_link)

        else:
            # Nothing to traverse
            if VERBOSE: print('Returning to upper level')
            return to_traverse_list, to_avoid_list, done_list, error_list, source_of_link


def match_any(my_string, regexp_list):
    if my_string:
        combined = "(" + ")|(".join(regexp_list) + ")"
        return re.match(combined, my_string)
    else:
        # 'None' as string always matches
        return True
```

Comment: this looks too complicated solution for the question!

Comment: Indeed, but takes care of URLs with arguments and actual (test) data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver


class WebPagesTests(TestCase):

    def test_static_pages(self):
        urls = get_resolver(None).reverse_dict.keys()
        #urls = ['get_started', 'website_about', 'website_hiring',
        #            'terms_of_service', 'privacy_policy']
        for url in urls:
            url = reverse(url)
            resp = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Nice and short, however it would not traverse urls with arguments correctly, right?

Comment: yes, it wouldn't. May be you should probably custom piece of code that will check the number and type or arguments needed for the url and pass some real/dummy data.

Comment: i gave some thought into validating the urls with arguemnts, but that doesnt seem to have simple solution, because lot of factors play in that situation. Lets day I have a url with pattern `r'^blog/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)$`, I have to make sure that the slug is simple string or numbers or some pattern (here im not using pattern) and even i could create text based on pattern, that new `slug`  should exist on the database, so to know that , i need to know the `model` of the blog.  So you might have to create your own solution for the onces with arguements or hard code them

Comment: Indeed. See my proposed solution below. More complicated, I agree, but works for me.

Comment: Dont suppose anyone has a simple way to differentiate between html responses and form endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your website online, you can use a standard link checker, which python has a couple of.

The one that I found to be easy to work with and install in python 3 was `pythonlinkvalidator` - https://github.com/bartdag/pylinkvalidator

`pip install pythonlinkvalidator`

`pylinkvalidate.py -P http://www.yourdjangosite.com/`

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But intention is to run this in a continuous integration environment, not on a production server.